# WP8 KnownContactProperties.Birthdate can not set value

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();
StoredContact sc = new StoredContact(store);
IDictionary<string, object> values = await sc.GetPropertiesAsync();
values[KnownContactProperties.FamilyName] =  "bbb";
values[KnownContactProperties.GivenName]=  "worerrrrld";

//*************problem here**************
Nullable<DateTime> birth = DateTime.Now;
values[KnownContactProperties.Birthdate] = birth;
//values[KnownContactProperties.Birthdate] = DateTime.Now;
//values[KnownContactProperties.Birthdate] = "2010-05-10";
//it will cause exception by any way above.
//***************************************

await sc.SaveAsync();//Exception throw here  :System.InvalidCastException
```

About windows phone8 API

`Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation` namespace

It's too weird about Class `StoredContact`!

Can any body help me! How to set this `KnownContactProperties.Birthdate`?

Comment: It doesn't work either when I tried using DateTime.Now.ToString() or other format string like"2010-05-10".System.InvalidCastException had been throwed.

Answer (score 5):

The InvalidCastException is normal since the expected object is DateTimeOffset.

Try this:

```
values[KnownContactProperties.Birthdate] = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Parse("2010-05-10"));
```

Regards.

Comment: I know my comment is very late, but I just encountered this problem myself. I did not manage to find any suitable answers on MSDN, as the documentation lacks in many aspects. Are the contact stores thoroughly documented anywhere on the web?

Comment: Also, I'm getting the same Invalid Cast Exception when trying to save an address, for `values[KnownContactProperties.Address] = myAddress` (where myAddress is a string). How can I save an address to the contact store? In the contact screen on the phone, the address area has lots of fields. Any way to access those?

Comment: You have to use this object to store addresses in a contact store: Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactAddress.