# ContactStore InvalidCastException on SaveAsync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task, contacts, async-await

I'm trying to save a contact to the Windows Phone (8) Contact Store.

My code doesn't do anything non-standard:

```
private async Task SaveContactToLocalStore(IMyLocalContact myLocalContact) {

    var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite,
                ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.LimitedReadOnly);

    var contact = new StoredContact(store);

    var properties = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWiteSpace(myLocalContact.Nickname) {
        properties.Add(KnownContactProperties.DisplayName, myLocalContact.Nickname);
    }

    /* Several such addition operations are executed, all identical, except for the values */

    await contact.SaveAsync();
}
```

Somewhere in a function marked `async` I call my save function with:

```
await SaveContactToLocalStore(myLocalCOntact);
```

I get the following error: `System.InvalidCastException` on contact.SaveAsync()

Full error text:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

I'm not sure where to even start investigating. Examples from MSDN work fine.

Comment: Stack makes it appear that you have an underlying exception. Running under a debugger with break-on-throw should help show the root exception.  The cast exception is less obvious, but is guess a mismatch of async CTP or other library with what it's using at runtime?

Comment: I've investigated a bit more and it seems that the conversion exceptions were thrown from trying to save an Anniversary or Birthdate with `KnownContactProperties.Birthdate`. MSDN clearly says (for `StoredContact.GetPropertiesAsync`): `In the current release, the values stored in the IMap returned by this method must be strings. `. I was trying to save these dates as `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`. MSDN documentation is very lacking...

Comment: Birthdate and Anniversary have been fixed according to the answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376342/wp8-knowncontactproperties-birthdate-can-not-set-value/14586007#comment22732259_14586007 -> I'm still having trouble with saving an Address though, as mentioned in my comments there.